# Why I get error while connecting to google using php imap_open without novalidate-cert flag

Tags: php, ssl, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to connect to google using host `imap.gmail.com` and port `993` but when I don't add `novalidate-cert` flag to `imap_open` function I get error as "Certificate failure for imap.gmail.com: self signed certificate in certificate chain". I am curious why I am getting this error. Why certificate validation is failing.

Answer (score 1):

either because google really uses self-signed certificates to save money. or someone is doing a man-in-the-middle attack on you.

ask your sysadmin wether he is doing any fancy SSL packet inspection stuff...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you don't have any trusted CAs configured for verification, or not the right ones. There is no good default setting with PHP, see also [PHP and SSL CA Verification - OS Independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298282/php-and-ssl-ca-verification-os-independent)